# How to query Laravel 5.1 Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have a projects table and an items table. Rents table is the middle eloquent. It shows what project rented or used what item. How can I retrieve a project and all items used without necessarily involving rents in the result.

Schema:

[image]

Projects

```
public function rents()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Rent');
}
```

Items

```
public function rents()
   {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Rent');
   }
```

Rents

```
 public function project()
   {
   return $this->belongsTo('Project');
   }
   public function item()
   {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Item');
   }
```

Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: I'm trying to get projects with all rented items, can't seem to get it right somehow

Comment: Would you share your DB design schema?

Comment: @MinaAbadir I jus edited the question, the schema image has a link. kindly fyi.

Comment: What are the foreign keys in Projects and Items tables?

Comment: @MinaAbadir the foreign keys are in rents. we have projects_id and rents_id

Comment: Your schema and Eloquent setup looks fine. What does your eloquent query look like? What error do you recieve?

Comment: *How can I retrieve a project and all items used without necessarily involving rents in the result.* - have you tried, `hasManyThrough` yet?

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve what you are looking for, you need to use a different relation `hasManyThrough`, simply adjust your `Project` models as below:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{
    public function items()
    {
      return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Item','App\Rent');
    }
}
```

Comment: that would not work. I tried it earlier. reason being that item doesn't have a column project_id. item is not related to projects at all. the only common ground is on a rents table. Pls shed more light on the solution if you think I'm still wrong

Comment: The `hasManyThrough` relation is exactly what you are looking for, it will get the relation Through an intermediate table. In this case the intermediate table is the rents table. So Project->rents->items can be translated into Project->items using this relationship. Are you sure, you really tried this relationship, what error did you get?

Comment: I got the error "column not found"  with this approach

Comment: it is looking for rents_id from in items. The query joins projects and rents on projects.id = rents.projects_id and then tries to join rents.id to items.rents_id in which case it fails cos it doesn't exist.

Comment: You are correct, it won't work. I have checked the documentation carefully, and it's not for you. I will update my answer.